# Take screenshot with Selenium: WaitForPageToLoad does not wait long enough

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm trying to get screenshots from a web page with multiple browsers. Just experimenting with Selenium RC, I wrote code like this:

```
var sel = new DefaultSelenium(server, 4444, target, url);
sel.Start();
sel.Open(url);
sel.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
var imageString = sel.CaptureScreenshotToString();
```

This basically works, but in most cases the screenshot is of a blank browser window, because the page is not yet ready for display. It kind of works if I add a sleep just after the WaitForPageToLoad, but that slows down the fast browsers and/or may be to short for the slower browsers (or under load).

A typical solution for this seems to be to wait for the presence of a certain element. However, this is meant as a simple generic solution to get a screenshot of a local web page with as many browsers as possible (to test the layout) and I don't want to have to enter certain element names or whatever. It's a simple tool where you just enter the Selenium Server URL and the URL you want to test, and get the screenshots back.

Any advice?

Comment: I just tried with Selenium Server 2.0 Alpha 5, and it seems to work in Opera, Internet Explorer and Chrome. It did not work reliably on Firefox though. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I use Selenium-RC to capture screenshots of remote pages where the waiting time is variant. In such cases, checking the title of the page and using time.sleep(n seconds) usually does it for me.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, no idea how to check for the page, which is not yet displayed. I can put wait point for object by using "Is Element present" but how it for window as there is no "window exist" command in selenium.

I am using:

    <click on a link in the 1st page>
    <I have to put a sync wait here, until the 2nd page display>

    selenium.SelectWindow("window Nme");
    selenium.IsElementPresent("object");`

My code is failing due to the 2nd window taking time to load.

I am using selenium RC with C#.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can make use of Browser status bar to verify whether that page is loaded fully or not. I think this is the best solution.